# Passing PHP variables into sql query

Tags: php, sql, variables, url

I would like to create a filter, and pass both category and the value into the sql query in the WHERE clause.
If i set manually the category, it gets the values and filters the results. But when I want to pass the category, it gives me this error.

[image]

Here is the code I use:

```
$('#filterEvents').click(function () {
    document.location.href = 'events.php?filter=' + $('#eventFilterOption').val() + '&filterValue=' + $('#eventFilterInput').val();
});
```

And the PHP processing:

```
$category = $_GET['filter'];
$searchValue = $_GET['filterValue'];

$sql = "SELECT EV_Date, EV_KKZ, EV_CardNr, TE_Name, EV_Name, EV_SurName, EV_EventTyp FROM events1
    INNER JOIN terminal1 ON terminal1.TE_IDX = events1.EV_FK_TermIDX
    WHERE ".$category." = '" . $searchValue . "'
    ORDER BY EV_Date DESC
    LIMIT 2000";

print_r($sql);

$query = $DB->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$data = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Dump the query out - the message states you've got syntax error.

Comment: Debug your code

Comment: You should check `$category` against a whitelist of allowed column names and you should bind a parameter for the value. This is one big sql injecion hole.

Comment: @jeroen, I get the value of `$category`, i can print it out. But when I try to use in the clause, it is not working properly. The thing is, I can use the othe value.

Comment: You are doing a `print_r($sql);`. What is the result of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the functionality a little you will be able to use the prepared query with bound params.

so say you have filters for colour and size at the moment looks like you would call urls like

```
events.php?filter=Colour&filterValue=Red
events.php?filter=Size&filterValue=Large
```

you could change to pass filter[name]=value

```
events.php?filterColour=Red
events.php?filterSize=Large
```

Javascript would look something like this

```
$('#filterEvents').click(function () {
    document.location.href = 'events.php?filter' + $('#eventFilterOption').val() + '=' + $('#eventFilterInput').val();
});
```

The query could be rewritten as follows (assuming columns of Size and Colour)

```
$sql = "SELECT EV_Date, ....
WHERE 
  ( '' = :colour OR Colour = :colour ) AND
  ( '' = :size OR Size = :size ) 
ORDER BY ....
```

and a call to bind the actual params added

```
$query = $DB->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':colour', $_GET['filterColour'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$query->bindParam(':size', $_GET['filterSize'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$query->execute();
```

This allows you to use prepared queries and avoid risk of SQL injection 
As a bonus (or bug) it could support multiple filter options at the same time

```
events.php?filterSize=Large&filterColour=Red
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem with getting the variables - the PHP script is not getting the values - so I believe you have a bug in your Javascript.

More importantly, this is not a safe way to run queries.  Your PHP is taking variables passed by the user and inserting them directly into SQL - with no validation.  It would be very easy to abuse this functionality to extract information or modify your database.

You should use the value of `$category` to select a known column and then use bind parameters to set `$searchValue`.

Answer (score 0):

You have empty values here:

```
$category = $_GET['filter'];
$searchValue = $_GET['filterValue'];
```

You should debug the method how you are getting them in js.
BTW you will always see that error when open this page /events.php. Because these variables will be empty by default.

Comment: The first load, is defaul display of the values from Database. When I start to filter them, there is the problem.

Comment: @MaximRoman I am not sure what you meant. But this error: https://ibb.co/k9Adpp because of $category and $searchValue are empty. I'm not sure what answer you want to get.